# Google Sheets - Query Malfunction

Tags: google-sheets

Say I have Sheet 2 data as below:

```
|----+----|
| A1 | B1 |
|----+----|
| A2 | B2 |
|----+----|
| A3 | 3  |
|----+----|
```

I want to use query to show it in Sheet 1 with below command:

```
=query(Sheet2!A:B)
```

But row 1 and 2 are merged together like the following table

```
|-------+-------|
| A1 A2 | B1 B2 |
|-------+-------|
| A3    |     3 |
|-------+-------|
```

If I change the number in B3 from "3" to "B3", then it works just fine. That means if it's a number, query API will not work as expected.

Is it a query API problem or my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the optional headers argument in QUERY. e.g:

```
=query(Sheet2!A:B,,1)
```

Alternatively use:

```
=index(Sheet2!A:B)
```

or

```
={Sheet2!A:B}
```

Comment: Oh, how did you figure out that? I never realize the optional header will impact on this case! :-)